# VBA: Copy/Past in new sheet including locking cells

Tags: excel, vba, security, locking, copy-paste

The Situation is this:

I have an Excel sheet, with Input workbook to fill in personal things and for every single month a workbook. Now, there is a button, when the user want to have a new Excel sheet, for reason of changing workplace.

So for example: Mr. Dean has filled in his daily hour work till April the 15. Now he move on the another Location and presses the button to hhange the worklocation. He gets a new Excel sheet, which exactely looks the same as before, filled in with the data that he wrote in from the first sheet (copy/paste from vba-sript). The existing entries (cells) till 15.April are also locked, so that he cant edit them. He continues to write down his hours for the 16. April and so on.

I think it is better, if the second Excel sheet gets created by the macro (copy/paste).

Name of the first sheet: sheet1
Name of the second sheet: sheet2

So my code doesnt worke so far:

```
Sub Test()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = sheet1.Worksheets("Master")
ws1.Copy sheet2.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
End Sub
```

That will copy the whole sheet?

This code is for Password protection for the woorkbooks. How can I lock just single cells till April 15?
So how do I have to read out the date?

```
Sub sbProtectAllSheets()

    Dim pwd1 As String, pwd2 As String
    pwd1 = InputBox("Please Enter the password")
    If pwd1 = "" Then Exit Sub
    pwd2 = InputBox("Please re-enter the password")

    If pwd2 = "" Then Exit Sub

     'Check if both the passwords are identical
    If InStr(1, pwd2, pwd1, 0) = 0 Or _
    InStr(1, pwd1, pwd2, 0) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You entered different passwords. No action taken"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Protect Password:=pwd1
    Next

    MsgBox "All sheets Protected."

    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Or do you have any other suggestions?

Greets 
Duc

Comment: The first Sub will copy the entire sheet1 after sheet2 (tab order). To lock a single cell you can use Sheet1.Cells(1,1).Locked = True, then you'll have to protect the sheet, but it's much easier to lock or unlock an entire range of cells like ("A1: F20)

Comment: Alright, so I won't use the Password-lock?

Comment: You can leave the password empty, and anyone will be able to unprotect it at any point, but if you use a password you'll need to find a way to store it so VBA can use it (like the Tag property of an object on one of the permanent sheets)

Comment: Have you attempted to run your code? For your `Sub Test()`, you're asking _if_ this will work, not _stating_ that it _doesn't_. I'm going to venture a guess that it won't work because it looks very, very wrong, but I don't know what kind of global variables you may have set outside the `Sub` you've shown us (or if you have `Option Explicit` set - you should). Please edit your post to include the exact error message(s) you're getting if you'd like to increase the chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: Please do not use the [**macros** tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info) for MS Office / VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have rows for each date, and that they follow each other. In the column the hours are entered you can find out the first one that is empty. I wrote this code for that a while back. Fill for +column+ the number of the column to which the hours are entered.

```
LastRowR = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For row = 2 To LastRowR
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(row, +column+) = "" Then
            LastRowR = row - 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next row
```

Then you can lock the range of cells that are in the past. So you can make a range from ("A1":Cells(LastRowR,+LastColumn+)) In which +LastColumn+ is the number of the last column that is used in your sheet.